# Querying for disjoint set

Tags: sql

I have put all the DDL and query in sqlfiddel  link below

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89c76/2

Same thing here

```
create table players(name varchar(32),playerid int);
insert into players values("a",1);
insert into players values("b",2);
insert into players values("c",3);
insert into players values("d",4);
insert into players values("e",5);
insert into players values("f",6);

select * from players;

create table matches(playerid int,game varchar(32));
insert into matches values(1,"game1");
insert into matches values(2,"game1");
insert into matches values(3,"game1");
insert into matches values(1,"game2");
insert into matches values(2,"game2");
insert into matches values(3,"game2");
insert into matches values(4,"game3");
insert into matches values(5,"game2");

select * from matches;

commit;

--This will give same players playing different games
select playerid,game
from matches
group by 1,2
```

Now say I want to list all the players who won't play a given game, say game1

- If player1 is playing game1 and game2 then it should not be returned as he is still
      playing game1 along with other games, in this case example it should return player 4 and 5
- If there is a player who is not playing any of the games in this case player 6, should also be returned
      as part of the result.

Here are my queries:

```
    select * from players 
where playerid not in (
    select playerid from matches m 
    where m.game = 'game1') /* 4,5,6*/

select * from players 
where playerid not in (
    select playerid from matches m 
    where m.game = 'game2') /*4,6*/   

select * from players 
where playerid not in (
    select playerid from matches m 
    where m.game = 'game3') /*1,2,3,5,6*/
```

How can I do this in a single query for all the games? There can be many types of games. I can't specify the games explicitly. Instead, I want to write the query to fetch all the `playerid`s who are not playing a game for each of the game some thing like this:

```
select * from players 
    where playerid not in (
        select playerid from matches m 
        group by game)
```

The above query is giving only one record. I need like this

```
Result:
------------------------
game1 | 4,5,6  
------------------------
game2 | 4,6
------------------------
game3 | 1,2,3,5,6
------------------------
....
```

**I was able to solve this problem, posting solution, so that, it will be useful for others**

```
select p.playerid,m.game
from players p, (select distinct game from matches) m
where p.playerid not in (select playerid from matches where game=m.game)
```

I get the correct result. Can it be improved further?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  You should explain what you want to do, provide sample data, and desired results.

Comment: Yes, I have put all the required data and output along with comments, please check the inline comments

Comment: Please go through the comments, I have explained everything along with working example

Comment: I need something like a for loop, to get this info for each game

Comment: Thanks much APC for formatting the post

Answer (score 0):

I think one single *sub-query* is enough to find the players who are not playing `game1` along with other players who are still not playing any game

```
select * from players 
where playerid not in (
    select p.playerid from players p 
    left join matches m on p.playerid = m.playerid 
    where m.game = 'game1')
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh Sharm, based on your answer I slightly modified the expected result. I have edited my question please check